# Oracle 10g to sql server 2012

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, sql-server-2012

We have to migrate from oracle to sql server. We are planning on using SSMA for oracle to setup the structures, then use SSIS move the data. 
We would like to keep both databases in sync for a while (approx 2 months) so that we can start transferring our old programs (around 300) to use sql server instead of oracle.
Is this possible and can anyone link a tutorial or walkthrough. or is there an alternative that we have not considered

thanx

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just curious, why are you moving to SQL Server from Oracle?

Comment: Quoted contract for next year is double what it is this year

Comment: This question is really too broad for StackOverflow - this is something that typically requires a significant investment of time and material, sometimes via a consultant or two, who will will have a better understanding of your ecosystem and your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle Golden Gate to replicate the data in a bi-directional way.